# How safe is a person from evil spirits if he is at sea or on a salt lake?

Tags: tv, supernatural

In the TV series *Supernatural*, the Winchester brothers regularly use salt in various forms to repel or kill evil spirits. Does this mean that a person who is at sea (and therefore surrounded by a high concentration of salt in the water and air) or at a salt lake will be safe from all except the most immune spirits and demons?

Comment: And why don't we make salt-filled spirit-proof body armor? And handy salt paste sealant tubes for sealing those cracks along your defensive perimeter?! All this can be yours for the low, low price of $89.95! Call NOW!

Comment: In the show they use shotgun shells filled with rock salt and lines of salt across doors and windows (entrances, basically) to either repel or prevent spirits and demons. I can't think of any other forms or uses, but it's probable that I've forgotten something. That aside, I don't think there's any evidence that suggests that salt dissolved in a liquid would or would not be as effective.

Comment: This is why Salt Lake City is free from ghosts.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, they never kill a ghost with just salt, they are need to spread salt on the remains (bones, body or something associated with the ghost) of the ghost, then burn the remains.

On repeated occasions, someone asks the Winchesters 'Why use salt or iron bars to repel ghosts?' They answered, 'Because they're pure materials'. So I think diluted salt would not work like pure salt.

In later episodes you can see, in order for a ghost to move an object they need a to concentrate and/or be enraged; when something pure "touches" the ghost (iron, salt etc.), they lose the ability to move objects (or even appear corporeal) for a small period of time.

By the end of the season seven you can see all these things.

Comment: someone could tell how to put spoiler text?

Comment: I think you've got it. It has to be pure salt, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to recall an episode about a ghost ship...

Yep...

[Red Sky at Morning](http://www.supernatural-fan-wiki.com/page/Red+Sky+at+Morning+Full+Recap)

I guess it's possible that the ghost ship was sailing in fresh water.  However, the cast iron rock salt coated panic room Bobby built seems pretty ghost/demon proof.  Even that was protected with devils snares and other mysterious symbols, though.